# Multiple column SQL joins in a table

Tags: asp.net, sql, join, inner-join

### Background:

Hi there, first time posting a question so please excuse any wrongdoings...
I have been given an assignment at university using ASP.NET and SQL Server, what we basically have to do is create a webform where we can select a political party via a radio button list bound to a SQL data source. Based on this selection, a drop-down list is then populated with a list of MPs who are a part of the party selected the radio button list. You can then select an MP and view his or her personal details, their roles in parliament and ask/view questions via a number of data controls linked to various SQL data sources.

I'm making good progress and trying to use whatever resources I can find to get solutions but alas I've hit a wall with viewing the parliamentary roles after selecting the MP.

I have 3 tables which are involved here:

```
MP                   MP_ROLES               ROLE
-------------        ---------------        ----------------
MP_NUM (PK)          MP_NUM (PK, FK)        ROLE_NUM (PK)
MP_FIRST             ROLE_1 (FK)            ROLE_DESCRIPTION
MP_LAST              ROLE_2 (FK)
MP_EMAIL             ROLE_3 (FK)
MP_CONTACTADD        ROLE_4 (FK)
MP_PHOTO
PARTY_NUM(FK)
```

(where `ROLE_1` through `ROLE_4` reference `ROLE.ROLE_NUM`.)

### Problem:

I have a `DetailsView` control which is bound to an SQL data source which queries `MP_ROLES`. What I'm basically trying to do is replace each value in `ROLE_1`, `ROLE_2`, etc. with the corresponding `ROLE_DESCRIPTION` value referenced by `ROLE_NUM` in the `ROLE` table (as `MP_ROLE.ROLE_1 = ROLE.ROLE_NUM AND MP_ROLE.ROLE_2 = ROLE.ROLE_NUM AND MP_ROLE.ROLE_3 = ROLE.ROLE_NUM AND MP_ROLE.ROLE_4 = ROLE.ROLE_NUM`). Now through my digging through textboxes I know in more simple applications you can do what I'm trying to do with the `INNER JOIN` function, however as I'm still learning I haven't quite got the syntax sorted to do what I want to do.

### What I have so far:

```
SELECT MP_ROLES.MP_NUM, MP_ROLES.ROLE_1, MP_ROLES.ROLE_2, MP_ROLES.ROLE_3, MP_ROLES.ROLE_4
FROM MP_ROLES 
INNER JOIN ROLE ON MP_ROLES.ROLE_1 = ROLE.ROLE_NUM 
INNER JOIN ROLE AS ROLE_3 ON MP_ROLES.ROLE_2 = ROLE.ROLE_NUM 
INNER JOIN ROLE AS ROLE_2 ON MP_ROLES.ROLE_3 = ROLE.ROLE_NUM 
INNER JOIN ROLE AS ROLE_1 ON MP_ROLES.ROLE_4 = ROLE.ROLE_NUM 
WHERE (MP_ROLES.MP_NUM = @MP_NUM)
```

I've been hung up on this for the last 8 trying to find a solution so if there is anyone who is able show me where I'm going wrong or perhaps kind enough to provide a solution it would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the = ROLE.ROLE_NUM. You have to specify the alias here too. Also I rearranged some numbers since your numbers were all mixed up.

```
SELECT MP_ROLES.MP_NUM
, MP_ROLES.ROLE_1
, MP_ROLES.ROLE_2
, MP_ROLES.ROLE_3
, MP_ROLES.ROLE_4 

FROM MP_ROLES

INNER JOIN ROLE AS ROLE_1 ON MP_ROLES.ROLE_1 = ROLE_1.ROLE_NUM
INNER JOIN ROLE AS ROLE_2 ON MP_ROLES.ROLE_2 = ROLE_2.ROLE_NUM
INNER JOIN ROLE AS ROLE_3 ON MP_ROLES.ROLE_3 = ROLE_3.ROLE_NUM
INNER JOIN ROLE AS ROLE_4 ON MP_ROLES.ROLE_4 = ROLE_4.ROLE_NUM

WHERE (MP_ROLES.MP_NUM = @MP_NUM)
```

Comment: Hi Wietze314, thank you for your solution. Is it possible from here to retrieve the relevant ROLE.ROLE_DESCRIPTION value which is referenced by ROLE.ROLE_NUM? This is the ultimate goal.
thanks,
Murray

Comment: @muzzcuzz92: In the `SELECT` clause, just replace e.g. `MP_ROLES.ROLE_2` with `ROLE_2.ROLE_DESCRIPTION`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though what I was actually aiming for can be done using the LEFT OUTER JOIN function:

```
SELECT 
MP_ROLES.MP_NUM, 
MP_ROLES.ROLE_1, 
MP_ROLES.ROLE_2, 
MP_ROLES.ROLE_3, 
MP_ROLES.ROLE_4, 
ROLE1.ROLE_NUM, ROLE1.ROLE_DESCRIPTION AS POSITION1, 
ROLE2.ROLE_NUM, ROLE2.ROLE_DESCRIPTION AS POSITION2, 
ROLE3.ROLE_NUM, ROLE3.ROLE_DESCRIPTION AS POSITION3, 
ROLE4.ROLE_NUM, ROLE4.ROLE_DESCRIPTION AS POSITION4 

FROM MP_ROLES 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ROLE AS ROLE1 ON MP_ROLES.ROLE_1 = ROLE1.ROLE_NUM 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ROLE AS ROLE2 ON MP_ROLES.ROLE_2 = ROLE1.ROLE_NUM 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ROLE AS ROLE3 ON MP_ROLES.ROLE_3 = ROLE1.ROLE_NUM 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ROLE AS ROLE4 ON MP_ROLES.ROLE_4 = ROLE1.ROLE_NUM 

WHERE (MP_ROLES.MP_NUM = @MP_NUM)
```